# Mac control-A/E shortcut in Netbeans

Tags: osx-lion, keyboard-shortcuts, netbeans-7

I'm new to Netbeans on Mac OSX, and i want to use the control-A/E shortcut to go to the beginning/end of the paragraph, but it don't seems to work in netbeans.

Does anybody knows a solution to make it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found the solution, it's just that this shortcut are overwritten by Netbeans, just had to change it.